# In Flask application what is the difference between @app.teardown_request and @app.teardown_appcontext?

Tags: python, flask

I was going through a flask application and found the use of `@app.teardown_request`.
Can anyone please demystify the real reason of using `@app.teardown_request` rather than `@app.teardown_appcontext`?

In other words what exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

`@app.teardown_appcontext` - Bind a function after each request, even if an exception is encountered.

`@app.teardown_request` - Registers a function to be called at the end of each request whether it was successful or an exception was raised. It is a good place to cleanup request scope objects like a database session/transaction.

https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/379

Comment: So, there is no difference?